# How to link between two documents uploaded in doc library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, html

I have a task where I have been given two documents(in word/.doc format). I need to create multiple links inside doc1 and clicking those should navigate to the respective sections in doc2. Both will be uploaded in SP library.

This approach works in local

```
<a href="doc2 url#sectionname">Linkof Doc1</a>
```

and in doc 2 simply `<a name="sectionname">`

But it's not working in SharePoint. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: If you upload both Word docs into the SharePoint library, then edit one Word doc and create a link to the other Word doc, does that not work? Links in Word docs are relative to the file location, so the files need to be *in situ* when the links are created.

Comment: I have resolved it by placing a bookmark in second doc and referencing it from first doc by #bookmarkmane.Thanks.